# Image resize from binary data using Intervention Image

Tags: laravel

I am trying to resize an image from data retrieved from mysql table, using Intervention Image package. Without resize it is working fine.
I am stuck at Image::make which returns no data.  Here is my code :

```
$data = DB::table('accounts')
      ->leftjoin('coatypes','accounts.type','=','coatypes.typeid')
      ->leftjoin('attachments','attachments.vno','=','accounts.code')
      ->where('accounts.type','=',$request->type)
      ->where('accounts.branchid','=',$branch_id)
      ->where('attachments.branchid','=',$branch_id)
      ->where('attachments.vtype','=','Customer')
      ->select('accounts.*','coatypes.typename','attachments.docfile')
      ->latest()->get();

foreach($data as &$d) {
  $decoded_image = $d->docfile;
  $encoded_image = base64_encode($d->docfile);
  $img = Image::make($decoded_image)->resize(100, 100);
  info($img);
}
```

Both encoded and decoded image returns blank data in log

```
[2020-02-07 15:51:01] local.INFO:   
[2020-02-07 15:51:01] local.INFO:   
[2020-02-07 15:51:01] local.INFO:
```

Comment: what is in `$d->docfile` ?

Comment: Binary data. Log shows like this: [2020-02-07 16:50:29] local.INFO: ����;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (usin

Comment: please try `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); echo $d->docfile; exit;` and edit your question with the outcome

Answer (score 0):

You either have already a base64 String in your DB and don't need the `base64_encode` or there is a path to the image on your system, in which case you would need to get the image contents first (with `file_get_contents`) before encoding it to base64.

BTW:
Intervention Image accepts also an image path as far as i know.

Comment: I tried directly $d->docfile, with base64_encode($d->docfile) and base64_decode($d->docfile) but its not returning any data

Comment: The image is stored in database, there is no physical existence of image file.